# PHP Google Maps Api returns ZERO_RESULT in valid request

Tags: php, google-maps

I am doing project and I need to fill my database with lat lng of address. I decided to use PHP and geocoding and I have big problem. PHP script returns ZERO RESULT, but when I try with web browser I have correct result.

```
$fulladdress = $street.$city;
$request= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".rawurlencode($fulladdress)."&sensor=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request) or die("url not loading");
```

When i printed $fulladdress, $request and xml status I have this:

?apino Kartuskie http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%3Fapino%20Kartuskie&sensor=true STATUS: ZERO_RESULTS

Answer (score 1):

You need to translate the polish chars, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

```
$fulladdress = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $street.$city);
$request= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".rawurlencode($fulladdress)."&sensor=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request) or die("url not loading");
```

Comment: I change encoding (like you show) but results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, if the query/response from google maps api has some diacritical signs, it's necessarry to include http header "Accept-Language'. In my case:

Doesn't work:

```
curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ul.+Zwyciestwa+44%2C+Dobre+Miasto'
```

Does work:

```
curl -s \
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ul.+Zwyciestwa+44%2C+Dobre+Miasto' \
-H 'Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode using UTF-8.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%C5%81apino%20Kartuskie&sensor=true
```